# Laggy animation effect

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, lag

I've written a class to give a paralax effect to an element within or behind a container.

The backbones behind the animation is this equation:

`coords = (windowTopY - topYPositionOfTheCurrentElement) / speed) * direction`

At first I thought this was laggy because of the `(windowTopY - topYPositionOfTheCurrentElement)` but it was still lagging.

Basically I'll im trying to do is move an image within a container, slower than it's content.

Example: http://lineabridge.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/ & Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SDmdM/1/

Here's the class it self:

```
$.fn.paralaxBackgroundImage = function(method, settings ){
    settings = $.extend({
        element : $('.paralaxImage'),
        magnitude : 2,
        direction : 1,
        winTop : 0
    }, settings);
    var methods = {
        start: function(currentElement) {       
            $(window).on('scroll.paralaxScroll', function() {
                settings.winTop = $(this).scrollTop();

                // Set the new coordinates on the current element
                currentElement.css({
                    marginTop: ((settings.winTop - currentElement.closest('.paralax').position().top) / settings.magnitude) * settings.direction
                });
            }); 
        },
        stop : function() {
            $(window).off('.paralaxScroll');            
        }
    }
    this.each(function() {
        if ((method == 'start' || method === undefined)) {
            methods.start($(this));
        }
        else if (method == 'stop') {
            methods.stop($(this));
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```

Comment: could you please share a working code on fiddle??

Comment: I could, but it would be pretty much replicating the link I have posted as an example, the majority of that site is using this plugin...

Comment: If your code is replicating the link- it would have worked

Comment: I don't understand why you can't see the problem on the page? I've posted the code that's causing the issue, do you just want something so that you can play with the code working on fiddle?

Comment: I have created a fiddle and edit my question so that others can see it, although the fiddle is winging that It can't find the method when it's right there in the shell, I don't understand that... http://jsfiddle.net/SDmdM/1/